# Jenkins: Trying to add a dumb slave but the option is missing, any idea how to add it?

Tags: centos6, jenkins

I've installed Jenkins 2.x on a server and now I'm trying to add a "Dumb slave" but the option is missing.

In [this official Jenkins tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines) it says that when creating a new node the option should appear but the only option I have is:

> Permanent Agent

Screenshot:
[image]

And I can't find the way to add this feature.

Anyone knows how to add it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the problem is in outdated Jenkins documentation. In 1.x version it was called "Dumb slave" and in modern versions "Permanent Agent". It is exactly the same.