# The option to "Launch slave agents via Java Web Start" is missing from new node configuration, how can I add it to the options menu?

Tags: linux, java, jenkins, slave

I'm following [this official Jenkins guide](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) in order to become familiar with the Jenkins Pipeline configuration.
One of the steps there is to create a dumb slave and set it to "Launch slave agents via Java Web Start" but for some reason this option is missing from my configuration, the only other options I have are:
[image]
I've made sure that `/usr/bin/javaws` exists on the machine.

Any idea how to add it to Jenkins New Node configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, the answer can be found [in another question I asked in the same matter](https://serverfault.com/questions/793619/jenkins-trying-to-add-a-dumb-slave-but-the-option-is-missing-any-idea-how-to-a) and it seems like the problem is in outdated Jenkins documentation.

In 1.x version it was called "Dumb slave" and in modern versions "Permanent Agent". It is exactly the same.

Comment: Launch command wording also changed.
WAS: "Launch slave agents via Java Web Start"
NOW: "Launch agent by connecting it to the master"
[Documented on S/O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56980939/598141)

Answer (score 49):

This question was asked elsewhere:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38740924

You have to enable the TCP port of JNLP agents to enable this option for slaves.

Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > TCP port for JNLP agents

Comment: There is no such option any longer.